# Irreducibility of principal series of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am trying to work out, as an example, irreducibility of principal series in $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and I seem to get contradictory results using results of different papers.

Let $\chi$ be an unramified character of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then, I get that the representation $i(\chi)$ (which we get by using $\chi$ as a character of the split torus, extending to a Borel trivially and then inducing to the whole group) is reducible iff $\chi(p)=q, 1/q,$ or $-1$ using one paper, and $\chi(p)=q, 1/q,$ or $1$ using another. The last result seems more natural but I can't get my head around what is wrong in the first case. Can someone tell me if any one of the above results is correct? I could showcase all of the work but it will make a long post, and since it is probably a very classical result if someone can just provide an answer to for which values of $\chi(p)$ this representation is reducible I think I will be able to figure everything out.

Comment: Could you indicate which papers you are using as reference?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the Weyl group in your case has order 2, so that
a principal series representation has *a priori* length at most 2, by the corollary on p. 104 of [these notes of Murnaghan](http://www.math.toronto.edu/murnaghan/course.html). By the same notes, if $\chi$ 
is unitary and $\chi(g)\neq\chi(wgw^{-1})$ as functions of $g$ for all $w\in W$, where $W$ is the Weyl group, then the corresponding principal series representation is irreducible. This is shown in the same notes. See proposition 8.2 in [these notes of Ngo](https://math.uchicago.edu/~ngo/Rep-p-adic.pdf) of Ngo for a criterion when a principal series with $\chi$ having trivial stabilizer can be reducible. I can also recommend these collected examples by Paul Garret (active on this site) [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~Garrett/m/v/primer_urps.pdf). They include a necessary and sufficient condition for irreducibility for $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p$.

In general one considers unitary principal series representations, when the quasicharacter $\chi$ is unitary. So I am not sure what to make of $\chi(p)=q$. Moreover given that $\chi$ is determined by its value on any uniformizer, the trivial character $\chi(p)=1$ will just give you functions on $G/B=\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q}_p)=\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Certainly the constant functions provide a one-dimensional irreducible subrepresentation, so this definitely isn't irreducible.